# display a variable like %%i in for statements in variable? batch

Tags: batch-file

How do I use a variable like %%i in a permanent variable?
(I don't really know the correct terms, so I hope anyone can figure out what I mean)

This is the code I am using:

```
@echo off
color 0f
goto number

:number
title number
cls
echo number of options?
set /p num=
goto option

:option
for /l %%i in (1,1,%num%) do (
cls
echo Name nr. %%i
echo Enter a option
set /p n%%i=
echo %%i = %n%%i% >> log.txt
)
goto select

:select
cls
echo %n2%
pause >nul
```

the "%n2%" works for whatever you put in second, but when I try to print it into a file ( echo %%i = %n%%i% >> log.txt ) it doesn't work.
I know the "%n%%i%" is not correct, But I don't really know what to actually put there.

Comment: Either use `call echo %%i = %%n%%i%% >> log.txt` or enable delayed expansion with `setlocal enabeldelayedexpansion` and change to `echo %%i = !n%%i! >> log.txt`

Comment: Use `!n%%i!` and `EnableDelayedExpansion`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Thank you @Aacini , it worked

Comment: If the information at the linked answer aids you, I invite you to upvote such an answer. **`;)`**

Answer (score 0):

```
:option
for /l %%i in (1,1,%num%) do (
cls
echo Name nr. %%i
echo Enter an option
set /p option%%i=
)
goto select

:select
set option>log.txt
cls
echo %option2%
```

You may like to consider this.

The command

```
set option
```

will show every environment variable that starts `option` in the format `option1=Gido`, which is why I changed `n` to `option` (there are other variables set that start `n`)